# Force Android 10 security and Google Play system update

Tags: android-management-api

Using Android Management for our dedicated devices with kiosk launcher.
With Android 10 the Android security patch level and Google Play system update version is inconsistent between devices. Some of the devices with an older Google Play system update of Sep 2019 have an issue with Bluetooth connection cache - this seems to be resolved in the Feb 2020 version of the Google Play system update when I manually force them to update.

Is there a way to force these to update or otherwise control the version? They don't seem to ever update on their own.

Answer (score 0):

For system updates in kiosk mode, it is highly recommended using [SystemUpdate](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#systemupdate) with [SystemUpdateType: WINDOWED](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#systemupdatetype) in your policy.

Here is an example:

```
   "systemUpdate": {
     "type": "WINDOWED",
     "startMinutes": 120,
     "endMinutes": 420
   }
```

There are no additional controls for the Android security patch level and the Google Play Services update. The patch level varies by OEM and Carrier, and Google Play Services updates roll out to all devices over time.